# Using 'compiler invocation arguments' in CMakelists.txt

Tags: eclipse, cmake

I have an Eclipse workspace with multiple projects. I am setting up CMake scripts for each project so that I could build these outside Eclipse. I have transferred individual project settings to respective CMakelists.txt files, no problems.

However, I am not sure how I add the following settings of Eclipse into CMake.

- Settings that apply to the Eclipse workspace as a whole (for example: Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Build > Build Variables)
- Project properties > C/C++ Build > Discovery Options > Compiler invocation arguments.

How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for things like [`CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS[_<CONFIG>]`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html) for the first and [`target_compile_options()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_options.html) for the second?

Comment: For the first, yes, if I added in the CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<MYCONFIG>, they helped. Either this or add_definitions() worked. Second: No. I have these flags set in Eclipse for Compiler invocation arguments: "-E -P -v". I am not sure how (if at all) they affect the compilation.